# make SVG object as droppable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, svg, jquery-svg

I had an SVG line(path) object in my web application and div as draggable.

I would likes to drag the "draggable" div in to the svg object. For that I have to make the SVG line(path) as droppable. with the following code I can make an html content as draggable / droppable.

```
 $(".path").droppable({
        accept: '.mpath',
        tolerance: 'touch',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            alert("dropped");
        }
    });
```

But please help how to make svg as draggable or droppable, So that I can drag and drop over the svg path

Thanks

Comment: Can this help you? http://bl.ocks.org/thudfactor/6611441